# How to open view tabbar controller from didSelectRowAt indexPath within storyboard in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a storyboard with tabbarcontroller. One of tab bar has a tableview and I want that when the user tap in a row from tableview open a detail view with another tabbar. **The problem is when I open detail view tab bar hides** . how to show tabbar at didselectrowatindexpath?

The code in didselectrowatindexpath:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let DVC=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsViewController") as! NewsViewController
        DVC.getImage=sneaker[indexPath.row]
        DVC.getNews=News[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DVC, animated: true)

    }
```

I have created single view application.I have created DiscoveryNewsTableViewCell.I populated the table view cell with two arrays 1-sneaker 2- News  array .I want when the particular array displayed ist tab of bar controller .But i did get these fields on first tab of tabbar controller .Here is the sample code for this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uSYl-4a1UQXpMXkSQ_l8aij6EH_v2yna/view?usp=sharing

Comment: DetailView is in another tabbar? you mean , we have to open another tabBarviewController in which one of the viewController is detailView. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
// setting these values in local storage using user defaults
    let currentObj = News[indexPath.row]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(currentObj, forKey: "currentOb")
    let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DVC=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsViewController") as! NewsViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: WHAT IS forKey: "currentOb" ?

Comment: @ajadka.. You want to set some value and need to send destination VC so here u need to set that value & retrive that values at destination Vc

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are pushing the viewController instead of TabBarController.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
    let DVC = tabBar.viewControllers[0] as! NewsViewController
    tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
    DVC.getImage=sneaker[indexPath.row]
    DVC.getNews=News[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)

}
```

In the above code replace 0 in

```
  tabBar.viewControllers[0]
  tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
```

with index of view controller you want to open.

And also in the line

```
   let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
```

**tabBar** has to be set as storyboard identifier for UITabBarController that you want to display as shown below.

[image]

Comment: On selecting row  Program caught in exception.Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'tabBar'.

Comment: that only I have shown in my image . Go to storyboard select the uitabBarController you want to display and then set the Storyboard ID as tabBar

Comment: Have you got it?

Comment: I have edited the .please download the code and solve the issue

Comment: @ajadka solved download the code and check. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k3X2AtmJRToiu3E1m-rJR93mfPjy7cMc

Comment: @ajadka have you seen it?

Comment: newsTitle and NewsImage field are not displayed .this is the issue

Comment: @ajadka I edited the code have a look. https://drive.google.com/open?id=10_xyJV7W0KUZHkdT8JUvSglmzyG4jfG7

Comment: @ajadka please upvote and accept the answer if the issue is fixed.